# Async method in an async method

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asynchronous

My question: How do I wait for the input from an async method before going on?

Some background info: I have a C# app which scans for a QR code, and then loads data on basis of the value scanned.
The above works, but now I want the app to ask whether the value scanned is the right card.

The applied code is as follows:

```
using ZXing.Mobile;
MobileBarcodeScanner scanner;
private bool Correct = false;
//Create a new instance of our scanner
scanner = new MobileBarcodeScanner(this.Dispatcher);
scanner.Dispatcher = this.Dispatcher;
await scanner.Scan().ContinueWith(t =>
{
    if (t.Result != null)
        HandleScanResult(t.Result);
});

if (Continue)
{
    Continue = false;
    Frame.Navigate(typeof(CharacterView));
}
```

`HandleScanResult(Result)` being (skimmed down):

```
async void HandleScanResult(ZXing.Result result)
{
    int idScan = -1;
    if (int.TryParse(result.Text, out idScan) && idScan != -1)
    {
        string ConfirmText = CardData.Names[idScan] + " was found, is this the card you wanted?";
        MessageDialog ConfirmMessage = new MessageDialog(ConfirmText);
        ConfirmMessage.Commands.Add(new UICommand("Yes") { Id = 0 });
        ConfirmMessage.Commands.Add(new UICommand("No") { Id = 1 });

        IUICommand action = await ConfirmMessage.ShowAsync();

        if ((int) action.Id == 0)
            Continue = true;
        else
            Continue = false;
    }
}
```

The problem is, `Continue` remains false the the moment `if (Continue)` is called in the 1st block of code, due to the message box being asynchronous and the app continuing to the if-statement before the message box is done.

I have already tried giving `HandleScanResult()` a Task return type and calling `await HandleScanResult(t.Result);`. This should make the app wait for `HandleScanResult()` before going on to the if-statement.
However, this returns the following error:

```
The 'await' operator can only be used within an async lambda expression. Consider marking this lambda expression with the 'async' modifier.
```

Hence my question on how to wait for the input before going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot wait until an `async void` method has finished. `Task` is the return type that allows callers to get some sort of signal indicating the operation has completed. You did the right thing changing that method to `async Task`.

As for the error message, it's telling you that you can get rid of the compiler error as follows:

```
await scanner.Scan().ContinueWith(async t =>
{
    if (t.Result != null)
        await HandleScanResult(t.Result);
});
```

Note the extra `async` before `t`.

However, just because this compiles, doesn't mean this is what you should be doing. You're making things overly complicated, and you don't need to use `ContinueWith` at all here. When you're in an `async` method body, the `await` operator that you're already using can do what `ContinueWith` would've done, but in a more straightforward manner.

```
var scanResult = await scanner.Scan();
if (scanResult != null)
    await HandleScanResult(scanResult);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I had the `ContinueWith` from some sample code, hence why I used it. Thank you again, I'd +1 if I had more rep ;-)